# Counting non-overlapping runs of non-zero values by row in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have the following Pandas `DataFrame`:

```
id | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 
1  | 3  | 0  | 10 | 25   
2  | 0  | 0  | 31 | 15  
3  | 20 | 11 | 6  | 5  
4  | 0  | 3  | 1  | 7
```

What I want is to calculate the number of non-overlapping runs of `n` consecutive non-zero values in each row, for various values of `n`. The desired output would be:

```
id | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | 2s | 3s | 4s
1  | 3  | 0  | 10 | 25 | 1  | 0  | 0
2  | 0  | 0  | 31 | 15 | 1  | 0  | 0
3  | 20 | 11 | 6  | 5  | 2  | 1  | 1
4  | 0  | 3  | 1  | 7  | 1  | 1  | 0
```

where e.g. each value in the `2s` column shows the number of non-overlapping runs of length 2 in that row, each value in the `3s` column shows the corresponding number of runs of length 3, and so on.

I wonder if there are any Pandas or Numpy methods to take care of this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "pairs of 2s and 3s". E.g. there are no 2's at all in the entire data frame (unless you count `id`, but I assume that's supposed to be an index?)

Comment: sorry for my english! I mean if there are 2 (or 3 or 4) non-zero values consecutively in a row. Do you have a suggestion to rephrase my question clearly?

Comment: Oh, I see. I think the best way to say that is exactly what you put in your comment: "2 (or 3 or 4) non-zero values consecutively in a row." I suppose you could call it "a **run** of 2 (or 3 or 4) consecutive non-zero values in a row." (It's definitely not a pair. A pair can only ever have two things.)

Comment: I tried to fix it :) thanks!

Comment: That helps. Let me make another edit to clarify it further. (I think any further changes will be easier to demonstrate than to explain.) After I finish you can roll it back or edit again if you don't like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach with [`2D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) to solve for any number of elements in a row -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2

n = 6
v = np.vstack([(conv2(df.values!=0,[[1]*I])==I).sum(1) for I in range(2,n+1)]).T
df_v = pd.DataFrame(v, columns = [[str(i)+'s' for i in range(2,n+1)]])
df_out = pd.concat([df, df_v],1)
```

**Basic idea**

The basic idea is that we could use a sliding window for summing the presence of non-zeros in each row. Let's say we are looking to see how many three non-zeros occur consecutively. So, we will use a sliding window of size `3` and get the sliding summations. All those places where the sliding windows have all three elements occurring as non-zeros would produce a summation of `3`. So, we look for summations that match `3` and count those. That's it! We loop through all windows sizes to catch all of `2s`, `3s`, etc.

Here's a sample run to count for `3s` on an array -

```
In [326]: a
Out[326]: 
array([[0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1]])

In [327]: a!=0
Out[327]: 
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [329]: conv2(a!=0,[[1]*3])
Out[329]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]])

In [330]: conv2(a!=0,[[1]*3])==3
Out[330]: 
array([[False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [331]: (conv2(a!=0,[[1]*3])==3).sum(1)
Out[331]: array([3, 1, 4, 2])
```

Sample run -

```
In [158]: df_out
Out[158]: 
   a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  2s  3s  4s  5s  6s
0   1   2   1   0   0   2   2   1   0   0   0
1   1   1   2   1   0   1   3   2   1   0   0
2   1   1   0   0   1   1   2   0   0   0   0
3   2   2   1   0   2   2   3   1   0   0   0
```

Please note that if the first column is `'id'`, then we need to skip it. So, we need to use `df.values[:,1:]` instead of `df.values` in the proposed solution code.

Comment: sir, when you get a chance could you please explain `[(conv2(df.values!=0,[[1]*I])==I).sum(1) for I in range(2,n+1)]` part?

Comment: Sir, what if I only want to check this at the tail of the dataframe?

Comment: @renakre What exactly do you mean by tail? The last row?

Comment: For example, if I want to get the sequences of 1s at the tail for this: (1, 2,35,6,3,2,1,1,1) I want to get 3. If no 1 at the end, then 0. Makes sense?

Comment: @renakre That looks like a different problem than the one here. So, consider posting a new question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

A solution managing the non overlapping feature.

```
def count(row,mins):
    runs=(row!=0).astype(uint8).tobytes().decode().split(chr(0))
    lengths=[len(run) for run in runs]
    return np.floor_divide.outer(lengths,mins).sum(0)
```

It use strings fast operations to find all the runs, then use //  to find how many non overlapping runs of given length you can build in each.

with `df:`

```
    a1  a2  a3  a4
id                
1    3   0  10  25
2    0   0  31  15
3   20  11   6   5
4    0   3   1   7
```

`np.apply_along_axis(count,1,df,[2,3,4])` returns

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

which is the expected result for `df`.